# Start Raspberry Pi without login

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I would like to ask you if there is any way to start raspberry pi (using Raspbian) without login and password and to move directly to the GUI. Like Windows for example.

Comment: This should belong to http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the keeping this up to date!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## Raspbian Wheezy:

Following was taken from [eLinux.org](http://elinux.org) [RPi Debian Auto Login](http://elinux.org/RPi_Debian_Auto_Login) page:

**Auto Login:**

In Terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/inittab
```

Scroll down to:

```
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 115200 tty1
```

and change to

```
#1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 115200 tty1
```

Under that line add:

```
1:2345:respawn:/bin/login -f pi tty1 </dev/tty1 >/dev/tty1 2>&1
```

Ctrl+X to exit, Y to save followed by enter twice

**Auto StartX (Run LXDE)**:

In Terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

Scroll to the bottom and add the following above exit 0:

```
su -l pi -c startx
```

## Raspbian Jessie:

Use `raspi-config`. If, for some magic reason this tool is not present on your system, install it:

```
sudo apt-get install raspi-config
```

**Hard way:**

[Link](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/43419/427). [Link](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3873/auto-login-with-gui-disabled-in-raspbian).

---

## UPDATE 2019.05

In recent distro there's a simpler way to fix this:

At command prompt, type `sudo raspi-config`, then:

- select option 3 in menu (Boot Options)
- select option B1 (Desktopp/CLI)
- select option B2 (Console Autologin)

Hit OK, exit all the way and restart.

*Update 2019.05* credit belongs to *Hasan A Yousef*.

Comment: Is there a way to extend this so it automatically opens IDLE and runs a python module at startup?

Comment: You can configure LXDE to autostart programs: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LXDE#Autostart_programs

Comment: This does not automatically log me in.  I still get prompted to enter username/password every time.

Comment: This no longer works as /etc/inittab doesn't exist.

Comment: Use `raspi-config`.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs It still asks for password.