# Start application automatically after some delay

Tags: boot, raspbian

I am working on a Raspberry Pi (with Rasbian). The board should run standalone (without login), so the application I developed should start upon each boot. But I would also like to be able to take the hand on the board locally (not using ssh). My requirements would then be:

1. boot
2. wait 1 minute - if there is any user interaction, skip 3.
3. launch application - this is a Python script

How would one do that?

Thanks for your help.

Julien

Comment: What kind of application? Why does it prevent you from using the Raspberry Pi? I don't really see the problem...

Comment: @snøreven: Thx. The type of application here has no importance. What I need is the application to start itself automatically without any login (as in [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17830333/start-raspberry-pi-without-login[/link]) but the auto-start should allow some grace period before effectively launching the app.

Answer (score 0):

In our /etc/rc.local you can specify extra programs for startup, with delay. For instance you can add this:

```
python x

# sleep time in seconds
sleep 60

python y
```

If you are looking to to this ONLY if there is user interaction, I would recommend a bash script that returns this as bool. That would be in place of the "python y" command you see there. Sorry, I don't have a script like that handy.